# Creation of an android emulator with Jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, emulation

I'm trying to build my android project on an integration server with Jenkins. In my Jenkins, I created a user "jenkins" with all powers and I installed some plugins : Git, Gradle and Android Emulator.

I configured my project with these plugins (git repository, gradle tasks and a emulator). I'm trying to create this AVD :

```
Android OS version : android-18 
Screen density : 160 
Screen resolution : HVGA 
Device locale : fr_FR 
Target ABI : armeabi-v7a
```

But I have this error :

```
Error : Unable to find a 'userdata.img' file for ABI armeabi-v7a to copy into the AVD folder.
```

What can I do ?

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had 3 ABI's installed for the Android version that I was trying to install on my new AVD. I removed the 2 that I didn't need (from within sdk/system-images/ANDROID VERSION WANTED), and I was able to install the new AVD.

Comment: Yes, it is a temporary solution but it isn't a good practice. My integration server download all packages of the SDK manager and I would like that jenkins use them to create some emulators.

Comment: Gerard, I usually do that too, but there has been some sort of bug with the eclipse update that prevents some to add a new AVD through the manager. I was forced to use the terminal, and I was getting that same error. I am not sure if it's related to the other bug. Your right though, it is just a quick fix.